# Checked boxes and Node JS

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm struggling to understand how `html check boxes` work with node Js and Express. I have a simple form in `EJS` and before I work further on the backend logic, I want to make sure that the correct values are being pulled through. I can't find any resources to help, so I've come here (but I may be being dumb and the answer is right under my nose).

Right now, every `console.log` is being returned `false`, rather than `true` when the check box is selected. I don't think it's my form, and it could be the backend in Express that isn't built correctly. Any help would be great.

**EJS**

```
<form action = "/results" method ="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="citysearch">City Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="citysearch" id="citysearch" placeholder="e.g. Los Angeles">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for = "Celcius">Celcius?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="celcius" id="celcius" checked="true">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Express/Node**

```
app.post('/results', function(req, res){

    var checked = req.body.checked

    if (checked == "true") {
        console.log("true");
 } else {
        console.log("false");
    }
});
```

Comment: First log what is being sent the your `req.body`. It's most likely `citysearch and celcius`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property in your req.body with name `checked`. Instead you have two properties: `citysearch` and `celcius`. Add value on your checkbox this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="celcius" id="celcius" checked="true" value="true">
```

and in your controller use this:

```
if (req.body.celcius) {
        console.log("true");
 } else {
        console.log("false");
 }
```

Note that if you don't check the checkbox, your req.body will have only one property, `citysearch`, because unchecked checkbox are not sent to controller.